# Clangd cannot find standard libraries in CLion

Tags: path, clang, clion

In CLion, Clangd underlines in red any includes from the standary C library like

```
#include "stdint.h"
```

and show a hint: 'stdint.h' not found. However it compiles and run fine. My guess is that Clangd doesn't have the standary library in the path.

**Question**:

Are there two different Path for Clangd and Clion ? Can someone point me out a direction to include the standard library in Clangd path.